# Reaction between NaCl and NaHCO3

Tags: reaction-mechanism, chemical-formula

Does NaHCO3 (aq) react with NaCl(aq)? I don't think they should undergo any reaction but in the online database it is showing that they react to form Na2CO3 and HCl. Is it correct?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the database search result?

Answer (score 3):

Use other online databases, unless you have misinterpreted the database info. Quoting the info would help.

Mixing $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ leads to the possibly violent reaction releasing big volume of CO2.

$$\ce{Na2CO3(aq) + HCl(aq) -> H2O(l) + CO2(g) + 2 NaCl(aq)}$$

Be aware that $\ce{NaHCO3(aq)}$ and $\ce{NaCl(aq)}$ mean $\ce{Na+(aq)}$, $\ce{HCO3−(aq)}$ and $\ce{Cl−(aq)}$, all being present side by side in sea water and human blood.

$\ce{HCO3−(aq)}$ does not react with $\ce{Na+(aq)}$ nor $\ce{Cl−(aq)}$, but it does react with water via several acido-basic reactions:

\begin{align}
\ce{HCO3-(aq) + H2O(l) &<=> H2CO3(aq) + OH-(aq)}\\
\ce{HCO3-(aq) &<=> CO3^2-(aq) + H+(aq)}\\
\ce{H+(aq) + OH-(aq) &<=> H2O(l)}
\end{align}

The fact that there are present ions $\ce{Na+(aq)}$, $\ce{CO3^2−(aq)}$, $\ce{H+(aq)}$ and $\ce{Cl−(aq)}$ does not mean there is formed $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$. Significant presence of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ would mean the solution is strongly alkalic while the same for $\ce{HCl}$ would mean the solution is strongly  acidic.

It is neither of that, it is just mildly alkalic because of $\ce{HCO3-(aq)}$. $\ce{CO3^2−(aq)}$ and $\ce{H+(aq)}$ are there just in traces and are independent on $\ce{Na+(aq)}$ and $\ce{Cl−(aq)}$.

Answer (score 0):

No reaction will occur for those two compounds.

They are both salts that will dissociate in water. The $\ce{HCO_3^-}$ ion will form a bland ph buffer, but nothing so extreme.

If any molecules of $\ce{HCl}$ will form, they will be instantly dissociated since hydrochloric acid is a strong acid and very soluble in water